# What feature strings could be requested from Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am using Google Cloud API java library for Android. And using Feature API from com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.Feature package.

```
com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.Feature.setType(MY_FEATURE);
```

Consider above as simple call.
I am looking for details of what all features, MY_FEATURE, could be requested in the form of string. Where to get those details? Any documentation?

I couldn't get it in regular search.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's this: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#Type

```
{
  "type": enum(Type),
  "maxResults": number,
}
```

[image]